# Loading Wordpress footer into a second Website

Tags: wordpress, webflow

I'm working on a website in Webflow, since the project is part of another platform, my client want to display the footer and header of their Website (which is in Wordpress) into the one I'm building. I thought I could solve it using Wordpress REST API but I can't seem to make it work. I'm not very experienced with coding and was wondering if there's any other solution for connecting their footer to the page I'm building.
Appreciate any solutions or suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

One solution maybe could be: create the footer as a separated page in your website, and then load it in the second website as a `<iframe>` tag:

```
<iframe src="https://<the_separated_page_url_containing_your_footer_here>" title="description" height="300" width="100%"></iframe>
```